# Assigning a spy to a nested JSON object method

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts, jasmine, karma-runner

I am currently working on testing some custom code for Highcharts. This code gets called when the `load` event is triggered, which in laymen terms means that `load()` gets called when the chart has been fully rendered.

When the chart is fully rendered, my custom code executes, and it would call `hide()` when certain conditions are met. The implementation of this isn't important to the context of this question.

My question is, I would like to spy on `hide()` which is nested inside a JSON object:

```
      const chart = {
        series: [{
          data: [
            { shapeArgs: { width: 10, height: 10}, dataLabel: { width: 20, height: 20, hide: jasmine.createSpy() }},
            { shapeArgs: { width: 10, height: 10}, dataLabel: { width: 20, height: 20, hide: jasmine.createSpy() }}
          ],
          type: HighchartsChartType.Column
        }]
      }

      jasmine.spyOn(dataLabel, 'hide')
      chartMapper().serialize().events.load.bind(chart).call() // triggers the load event
      expect(dataLabel.hide).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Just for some extra detail, `dataLabel` is this following Highcharts [property](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels). The code `chartMapper()` consumes my `chart` object which generates the series and forces a `load` event to be triggered which would run the code I'd like to test.

I've attached two spies to the `hide` object within `data.dataLabel`. I want to check if either spies have been called, however, I am getting the error of:

```
ReferenceError: dataLabel is not defined
```

Because `hide()` is inside an array of points assigned to `dataLabel`, I'm not quite sure how to get around this. I've tried something like `data[0].dataLabel` for the expect statement, but that just says my index doesn't exist.

Comment: Ummm where was `dataLabel` declared?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. `dataLabel` is [this](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels) Highcharts object. My setup code creates that series object, which is what `chartMapper().serialize()..` does work on. As you can see in the `series` JSON object, there's a `dataLabel` in there.